# Express perform a function before responding

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express    = require('express');     
var app        = express();                
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;    

var router = express.Router();             

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  var test;
    function SomeFunction(){

      ....some function that calculates a value

      res.json({ message: 'Your value is' +  test }); 

    }






});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port);
```

I want to perform some function to calculate a value before returning it. As is stands the server will respond immediately. I am sure this is very basic but i looked everywhere and cant find an answer about how to wait for my express server to calculate the value before issuing a response.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your function **SomeFunction** anywhere. If you call it, express will wait. Just write after the function definition: **SomeFunction();**.

Comment: Thank you! That is right, stupid to have missed it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var express    = require('express');     
var app        = express();                
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;    

var router = express.Router();             

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  var test;
    function SomeFunction(res){

      ....some function that calculates a value

      res.json({ message: 'Your value is' +  test }); 

    }

    //call it with res parameter
    someFunction(res);





});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Yes, for simple calculation it's correct but if you have any async method in that function like db call or something like that then that res will not be in the scope of resolve state of that call that's why I sent it as parameter so it will be accessible in any situation.